# How to wrap RecyclerView items horizontally and vertically at the same time?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-gridlayout, recyclerview-layout

The Items should look like this:
[RecyclerView items as grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26PZ3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simply can be done using GridLayoutManager insted of LinerLayoutManager and without nested RecyclerView or any additional Layout like this:

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mRecyclerGrid=new GridLayoutManager(this,3,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mRecyclerGrid);
```

You can set how many items should appear on a row (replace the 3).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming an arbitrary number of columns and rows, you could try using [this library](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout) with a FlexboxLayoutManager for your RecyclerView. As you noted, you could also use a GridLayoutManager in case your columns are fixed.

Comment: Thank you so much Karan, I already answered my question but can you give your opinion on my answer?